# How do I fix an useEffect infinite loop with two properties bound that need to update at the same time?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I have an Autocomplete component:

**Autocomplete**

```
function Autocomplete() {
    const [ matches, setMatches ] = useState([ 'game' ]);
    const [ query, setQuery ] = useState('');
    const [ menuState, setMenuState ] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => { 
        if(query !== ""){
          updateQuery()
        }
    }, [query])

    const updateQuery = async () => {
        const data = await props.searchQuery(query);
  
        if(data.length > 1 ){
          setMenuState(true);
          setMatches(data);
        } else if (data.length < 1){
          setMenuState(false);
          setMatches([]);
        }
    }
    

    return (
        <div className={rootClassName(null, [props.className], classStates)} style={styles}>
          <div className='Autocomplete__Trigger'>

            <input
                className='Input'
                type='text' 
                placeholder={props.placeholder}
                value={query}
                onChange={ e => setQuery(e.target.value) }
                onKeyDown={ handleKeyPress }
            />
              
          </div>
          <div className='Autocomplete__Menu' role='menu'>
            {
            //Custom if function
              If(matches.length > 0, () => (
                <div className='Autocomplete__Content'>
                  {
                    //Custom loop
                    For(matches, (item, index) => (
                      //loops through matches
                    ))
                  }
                </div>
              )).EndIf()
            }
          </div>
        </div>
      );
  }
  
 export default Autocomplete;
```

Basically how it works is as follows:

1. When something is typed into the input a query string is set:

```
<input
    onChange={ e => setQuery(e.target.value) }
/>
```

2. The query state is set immediately with `useEffect` and `updateQuery()` is called:

```
useEffect(() => { 
    //If input is empty
    if(query !== ""){
        updateQuery()
    }
}, [query])
```

3. In `updateQuery()` all of the menu items in the autocomplete are requested from an API and the matches are set to be looped through and dictate whether a menu is open:

```
const updateQuery = async () => {
    const data = await props.searchQuery(query);

    if(data.length > 1 ){
      setMenuState(true);
      setMatches(data);
    } else if (data.length < 1){
      setMenuState(false);
      setMatches([]);
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is the matches state lags behind, but if I add it to `useEffect` I get an infinite loop because `updateQuery` is always being called:

```
useEffect(() => { 
    //If input is empty
    if(query !== ""){
        updateQuery()
    }
}, [query, matches])
```

How can I make it so matches and the query state are updated at the same time without an infinite loop?

Comment: Put the updateQuery  inside the useEffect.

Comment: Why is it important that the query and the matches be set at the same time? They're sequential actions, aren't they? 1. User enters search query. 2. At some future time, matching results are returned.

Comment: @ChrisFarmer because when I remove everything from the `query` string there is still matches; which keeps the menu open.

Comment: @Nikki9696 that works! If you want please answer so I can award the answer to you

Answer (score 0):

You can put the dependent code INSIDE the useEffect with the call to it.
That way, the function isn't re-declared every render. It only changes when the effect is re-run.

This might be missing an await or async modifier somewhere, but to give the idea.

```
useEffect(() => { 
const updateQuery = async () => {
        const data = await props.searchQuery(query);
  
        if(data.length > 1 ){
          setMenuState(true);
          setMatches(data);
        } else if (data.length < 1){
          setMenuState(false);
          setMatches([]);
        }
    }
    //If input is empty
    if(query !== ""){
        updateQuery()
    }
}, [query])
```